# Isomorphism of Groups - Show it has a solution

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: Let $\Phi : S \to \bar{S}$ be an isomorphism of $\left< S, * \right>$ with $\left< \bar{S}, \bar{*} \right>$. Suppose the equation $x * x = c$ has a solution for every $c$ in $S$. Show that $x ~\bar{*}~ x = d$ has a solution for every $d \in \bar{S}$.

---

My question is how do I even begin to solve this problem? It would make some sense to me if the 2nd equation was $\bar x ~\bar{*}~ \bar x = d$, but not when both equations only make use of regular x. I don't know what to do to in order to show the 2nd equation. If I can get any hints as to how I can begin solving this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up some versions of your question in the edit.

Comment: What you need to do is carefully understand what it means that "the equation $x*x=c$ has a solution for  every $c$ in $S$" i.e. it means "for all $c \in S$ there exists $x$ in $S$ such that $x*x=c$" Similarly the phrase "$x \bar{*} x = d$ has a solution for every $d \in \bar{S}$" means "for all $d \in \bar S$ there exists $x$ in $\bar S$ such that $x*x=d$" After that it should be clear to you that $x$ in the first statement just represents some element of $S$ and has nothing to do with $x$ is the second statement which represents some element in $\bar {S}$.